# Java: float[][] points

Tags: java, floating-point

I am using an open source program but I don't understand how I should write this class.

**Room**

```
public Room(float[][] points)
Creates a room from its name and the given coordinates.
```

I guessed it was something like

```
Room Parallelogram_Room = new Room{{0f,0f},{0f,400f},{625f,400f},{625f,400f},{625f,0f},{0f,0f}};
```

but it gives an error, or

```
Room Parallelogram_Room = new Room([0f][0f]);
```

but still gives an error.

Please, I am stuck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're messing up the syntax. Wrap the array with parenthesis.

To make it more clear, create the array *and then* pass it into the constructor.

```
float[][] points = {{0f,0f},{0f,400f},{625f,400f},{625f,400f},{625f,0f},{0f,0f}};
Room Parallelogram_Room = new Room(points);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Room room = new Room(new float[][] { {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6} });`